# Tkinter: Getting Canvas Attribute and Options Values

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, tkinter-canvas

I imagine this is a fairly basic Tkinter question - but I am a noob and I haven't seen this answer after some searching.

I would like to be able to check what the attribute of my canvas is in Tkinter. 
So,

```
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, 200,200, bg="blue") 
canvas2 = tk.Canvas(root, 200,200, bg="red")
canvases = [canvas, canvas2]
```

What I am looking for is something to check what the attribute is of the canvas. For example -

```
for canvas in canvases:
   if canvas.get_color() == "red": # IS THERE SOMETHING LIKE get_color... or get_attr(bg)? 
        print("HECK YA")
   else:
        print("I'm feeling blue")
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can call `canvas.config('attribute')` to obtain the value of a given attribute.
For instance `canvas.config('bg')` returns the value of the background.

Calling `canvas.config()` without arguments will return a dictionary of the current configuration

#### [Universal Widget methods that relate to configuration of options](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/universal.html):

> The methods are defined on all widgets. In the descriptions, w can be any widget of any type.
>
> **`w.cget(option)`**: Returns the current value of option as a string. You can also get the value of an option for widget w as w[option].
>
> **`w.config(option=value, ...)`**
>   Same as .configure().
>
> **`w.configure(option=value, ...)`**
>   Set the values of one or more options. For the options whose names are Python reserved words (class, from, in), use a trailing underbar: 'class_', 'from_', 'in_'.
>
> You can also set the value of an option for widget w with the statement `w[option] = value`
>
> If you call the `.config()` method on a widget with no arguments, you'll get a dictionary of all the widget's current options. The keys are the option names (including aliases like bd for borderwidth). The value for each key is:
>
> for most entries, a five-tuple: `(option name, option database key, option database class, default value, current value)`; or,
>
> for alias names (like 'fg'), a two-tuple: `(alias name, equivalent standard name)`.

Comment: `.config()` returns more than just the configured value. `.cget("background")` will return the configured background color, but `.configure("background")` will return more information than just the value.